# wildcard, same field, sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm getting zero results when I'm trying to query in the same field with one being a wild card. When I write it separate it works but I can't figure it out in the same table.

```
Select *
from table
where table.field1 NOT IN ('UNK')
OR table.field1 NOT LIKE ('x01%')
```

Comment: Add sample data to this question, but my hunch is your `OR` should be an `AND`

Answer (score 1):

Logic with `NOT` is tricky.  I think you want `AND`:

```
Select *
from table
where table.field1 NOT IN ('UNK') AND table.field1 NOT LIKE ('x01%')
```

The problem with your statement is that `'UNK'` is not like `'x01%'`.  So, if the first evaluates to false, the the second will evaluate to true.  The `AND` fixes this problem.